# #+include plantuml source in org file?

Tags: org-mode

I have a large plantuml sequence diagram in blah.iuml.  I would like to include it in my org-mode file so that it gets regenerated and included each time I export the org file to html.  I don't want to maintain the file separately, and not just insert it into the org file.  I'd hoped that something like this would work

```
#+begin_src plantuml :file blah.png
#+include "./blah.iuml"
#+end_src
```

I can see that it is trying to run plantuml on a file that contains

```
@startuml
#-include "./blah.iuml"
```

That is, the include is not doing an actual include when inside a #+begin_src.

Is there a way I can tell org-mode: "run plantuml on this file and pop the result into the generated html"?

Comment: Instead of wrapping the `#+include` statement in a src block, try: `#+INCLUDE: "./blah.iuml" src plantuml`

Comment: Thanks!  I got it to work with this: `#+include "./blah.iuml" src plantuml :file blah.png`

Comment: Welcome! Please post the accepted answer from comments. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
#+begin_src plantuml :file ./0003_files/layout_architecture.svg
@startuml
!include 0003_files/layout_architecture.puml
@enduml
#+end_src
```

the `layout_architecture.puml` also contains `@startuml` and `@enduml`.